# Using To_signed VHDL, "No feasible entries for subprogram To_signed"

Tags: vhdl

I'm working on a delay unit for a sound synthesizer on a FPGA, but when trying to compile in Modelsim to simulate i get the following error:
"No feasible entries for subprogram TO_SIGNED".
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

```
ENTITY Delay IS
    -- Delay time in ms
PORT(
    Sample  : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0);
    Delay   : in INTEGER RANGE 0 to 2000;               -- Echo Delay in ms, <2s
    Gain    : in INTEGER Range 0 to 7;              -- Gain of the Echo, 0/8 to 7/8
    clk     : in STD_LOGIC;
    Reset   : in STD_LOGIC;

    Output  : Out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0)
);
END Delay;

ARCHITECTURE Delay_Arch OF Delay IS 
    BEGIN
DelayOffset <= Delay*40;                                              -- Number of steps back in the buffer for x ms delay
Process(clk)
BEGIN
IF (Reset = '1') THEN                                                 -- Standard Reset
    CircBuffer <= (OTHERS=>(OTHERS=>'0'));
    Counter <= 0;
ELSIF RISING_EDGE(clk) THEN
    CircBuffer(Counter) <= Sample;                                    -- Save Data in to circBuffer

    IF (DelayOffset > Counter) THEN                                   -- Wrap around for counter
        OutBuff(11 DOWNTO 0) <= CircBuffer(79999-(DelayOffset-Counter));
    ELSE
        OutBuff(11 DOWNTO 0) <= CircBuffer(Counter-DelayOffset);                      -- Load sound from previous Sample (Delay)
    END IF;
    OutBuffInt <= (To_integer(Signed(OutBuff)) * Gain);                   -- Multiply with gain
    Outvect <= To_signed(OutBuffInt, Outvect'length);  <----- ERROR
    Output <= Outvect(14 DOWNTO 3);
    IF (Counter = 79999) THEN 
        Counter <= 0;
    ELSE
    Counter <= Counter + 1;
    END IF;
END IF;
END PROCESS;
END ARCHITECTURE;
```

I can't find any problems in the code. Is there something that i am missing, or is just the to_signed not working correctly?

Comment: Signal declarations are missing from the architecture, and you have a identifier named `Delay` which is the same as the entity name, so you probably get other warnings from ModelSim.  But anyway, VHDL uses overloading of functions, so it is not enough that a function with the name is available, it must also be available with the combination of argument types that the function is called with, but with the missing declarations it is not possible to see if this is actually the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems here as Morten Zilmer points out. But to answer what you asked, the "No feasible entries for subprogram" error means that the types of the arguments and/or target of the function call does not match any available declarations. In your case there is only one function named `to_signed` visible, which is defined like this in ieee.numeric_std:

```
function TO_SIGNED (ARG: INTEGER; SIZE: NATURAL) return SIGNED;
```

You did not include your signal declarations, but I would guess that your `Outvect` signal is declared as `std_logic_vector` and not `signed`, hence the error.